# Ports used by Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 .NET client library?

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I am using "Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 .NET" client library to read and send data to BigQuery.
What ports are used by this client library ?
I have a couple of servers and the code is working on some servers but not others. 
Any other ideas to troubleshoot this is helpful. Here's a code snippet that I am using.

```
var fs = new FileStream(_BQConn.JSONKeyFileName, FileMode.Open);
_log.Debug($"Reading JSON Key File ");
GoogleCredential googlecreds = GoogleCredential.FromStream(fs);
_log.Debug($"Running query on project {_BQConn.ProjectId}");
BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(_BQConn.ProjectId, googlecreds);
_log.Debug($"Running query {Query}");
Task<BigQueryResults> TaskData = client.ExecuteQueryAsync(Query,null,null , null);
BigQueryResults data = await TaskData;
```

Error Info:

```
CatchError - Reading SQL data from BQ. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
```

`A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest1.<ExecuteUnparsedAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --`

Comment: Bigquery is using the default port 443 for https request. Why do you think the error is related to port? What is the excat error you are getting?

Comment: Yup, we just make HTTPS requests. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Please provide a more detail error message

Comment: Added error message in original question

Answer (score 0):

It is a proxy issue, but Kishore's answer is not the solution.
I was able to use a Proxy using BigQueryService using this [post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/accessing-google-cloud-apis-though-a-proxy-fe46658b5f2a)
 but I haven't figured it out using the BigQueryClient. Posted a new question on stack overflow for this.

Answer (score -1):

Could be a proxy issue, Please go through below url:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings

---

above might help, keep me posted if it works.

Comment: That wouldn't make any difference to what the .NET client library does. While it might indeed be a proxy issue, those instructions are for configuring the gcloud SDK. (I would suggest that answers based on an expectation of it being a proxy issue probably aren't ideal until we have more information.)